# Cannot pull image from AWS ECR repository using docker with VirtualBox or Colima

Tags: macos, docker, amazon-ecr

### The Situation

As you may all know, Docker has changed its license for [Docker desktop to limit free usage for limited use cases](https://www.docker.com/blog/updating-product-subscriptions/).

As a result, I have resorted to alternatives such as [Colima](https://github.com/abiosoft/colima) and [use of virtual box](https://medium.com/crowdbotics/a-complete-one-by-one-guide-to-install-docker-on-your-mac-os-using-homebrew-e818eb4cfc3) as a means to continue using docker CLI while respecting Docker's new changes.

While it works fine for pulling images from Docker Hub, I've noticed that I can no longer pull images from my company's AWS ECR repo. The reason is due to unknown certificate authority issues.

My understanding of how docker runs is limited, but the gist I got from [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43383276/how-does-docker-run-a-linux-kernel-under-macos-host) is that docker CLI acts as the client for the developer to send commands to the Docker Daemon that runs on a virtual machine. So this issue is most likely related to the VM that the docker daemon is running on.

### The Error Message

```
Pulling from myrepo/myapp
5ad559c5ae16: Pulling fs layer
d7a7f7e76287: Pulling fs layer
3eb3e996f0d7: Pulling fs layer
d8f3fbab0eaf: Waiting
d310dd0da683: Waiting
6f542466a6be: Waiting
8851a2099770: Waiting
f1dd90cdff4b: Waiting
4a852bd6c6f1: Waiting
538106d55e7d: Waiting
dbc972867db8: Waiting
2bc8828e78a2: Waiting
1a653b47f557: Waiting
877c2f613a70: Waiting
09eac264496b: Waiting
66dd8ce5c695: Waiting
ccde39d6cfef: Waiting
4351b359c9e4: Waiting
52e095209afc: Waiting
c6ad9f161855: Waiting
233f3e28c5a3: Waiting
error pulling image configuration: Get https://prod-ca-central-1-starport-layer-bucket.s3.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/<a-very-long-hash>/<another-very-long-hash>?X-Amz-Security-Token=<AWS-security-token>&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20220210T215140Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=3600&X-Amz-Credential=<my-credential>&X-Amz-Signature=<amazon-signature>: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

### My hypothesis for why I'm getting this error message

This is purely a guess. Please feel free to correct me.

I know that with Docker Desktop, I do not get this certificate error and my guess is that with the integration of hyperkit, it the VM can run via localhost, which will allow Docker Daemon to tap into macOS' trusted certificate authority certs.

The problem now arises because the VM that I've obtained from the Internet now no longer has access to those trusted certs.

### What I've tried

1. Ensure I've logged into ECR using AWS command  `aws ecr get-login-password --region ca-central-1 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin <my-aws-account-id>.dkr.ecr.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com`
2. reinstall both Colima and the virtual box hypervisor
3. Isolate the issue by experimenting solely on virtual box setup.

I noticed that the folder /etc/docker is present on the VM. From [Docker's documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/certificates/), the default directory for certificates for docker is in /etc/docker/certs.d to which I noticed it is absent in my Virtual Machine installation.

I think I'm close to a solution, but I'm quite new to how certificates work and I'm not sure where I can obtain the certificates I need to put them into that path to test.

Does anyone know how this can be done?

Comment: Do you work for a company with 250+ people and/or $10M in revenue?  It's still free for many use cases.

Answer (score 1):

I got into same issue, I did this and it worked

```
Remove the line "credsStore": "xxx" from ~/.docker/config.json.
```

Answer (score 0):

When I've come across this error I needed to make sure that the company self-signed cert was known to Colima.

You can start Colima with:

```
colima start --edit
```

Then in the config file it opens you can find the `docker` section to add your insecure registries:

```
docker:
  insecure-registries:
    - my.private-registry.com:5000
```

source: [Colima FAQ adding insecure registries](https://github.com/abiosoft/colima/blob/main/docs/FAQ.md#how-to-customize-docker-config-eg-add-insecure-registries)

If that didn't work then additionally you can edit further down in the config and add in a small script to make sure the ROOTCA cert is placed into the VM file system under the `provision` section, e.g.:

```
provision:
  - mode: system
    script: |
      #!/bin/bash
      wget http://my.private-cert-endpoint.com/MY-PRIVATE-ROOTCA.crt -P /tmp
      openssl x509 -in /tmp/MY-PRIVATE-ROOTCA.crt -inform DER -out /tmp/MY-PRIVATE-ROOTCA.pem -outform PEM
      cat /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt /tmp/MY-PRIVATE-ROOTCA.pem  > /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

source: [Pull Request bringing in provision scripts into Colima](https://github.com/abiosoft/colima/pull/386)