# What types of docker images can run on docker desktop on mac?

Tags: docker, virtual-machine

In my understanding, docker on mac can run both macOS images and linux images but not other images like window images.

When running macOS images, docker only manage the resources. But when runing linux images, docker use the linux VM to supports the linux image?

Am I correct? Is it true that docker can only run images that are either compatible with the host or compatible with the linux VM within the docker application like docker desktop on mac?

Comment: Does [How does Docker run a Linux kernel under macOS host?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43383276/how-does-docker-run-a-linux-kernel-under-macos-host) answer your question?  In fact, the Docker Desktop application runs a Linux VM (even on a Linux host).